# Measure of a set on $\mathbb R$

Tags: measure-theory

> Prove that $$\forall A \subset \mathbb R, m^*(A)=\inf\{m^*(O):O \text{ open },A\subset O\}$$

I'm trying to prove both sides of the inequality.

I've got that $m^*(A)\leq \inf\{m^*(O):O \text{ open },A\subset O\}$ because $A\subset O$.

How should I proceed to get the other side of the inequality?

The definition that I can see may be useful is that of an outer measure:
$$\mu^*(A)= \inf\left\{\sum^\infty_{j=1}|I_j| \text{ for any } \{I_j\}^\infty_{j=1} \text{ open cover of }A \text{ by intervals}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a sequence of open intervals $(I_n)$ covering $A$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(I_n) \leq \mu^*(A) + \varepsilon$. But $G = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ is an open set containing $A$ and $\mu^*(G) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(I_n) \leq \mu^*(A) + \varepsilon$.
Since $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(G)$ whenever $A \subset G$, the assertion follows. (Notice that the only property that is being used is countable subadditivity)

Comment: Can I just clarify that you know such a sequence exists by the definition of infimum in the outer measure?

Comment: You get it from the definition of outer measure. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, $a = \inf(A) \Rightarrow \exists b \in A $ such that $ b < a + \varepsilon $.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** An open cover of $A$ by open intervals is *exactly* the same as an open set containing $A$ because any open set in $\mathbb R$ can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals.